# Is the space of smooth functions dense in that of continuous ones?

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, banach-spaces, uniform-convergence, smooth-functions

In this morning class about **Brouwer fixed-point theorem**, my professor admits a lemma without proof that

> **Lemma:** Any continuous function $f$ from a compact subset $C$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ can be uniformly approximated by a sequence of smooth functions $(f_{k})$. That is, $$\forall k \in \mathbb{N},\left\|f-f_{k}\right\|_{\infty}=\max_{x \in C}\left\|f(x)-f_{k}(x)\right\|<\frac{1}{k}$$

This lemma makes me remember of Weierstrass Approximation theorem in which a polynomial is a typical smooth function.

> **Weierstrass Approximation Theorem:** Suppose $f$ is a continuous real-valued function defined on the real interval $[a, b] .$ For every $\varepsilon>0,$ there exists a polynomial $p$ such that for all $x$ in $[a, b],$ we have
>   $|f(x)-p(x)|<\varepsilon$, or equivalently, the supremum norm $\|f-p\|_\infty<\varepsilon$.

I would like to ask if the following statement holds:

> Let $E,F$ be Banach spaces, $X \subseteq E$, and $f: X \to F$ is continuous. There is a sequence of smooth functions $(f_k)$ in $\mathcal C^\infty (X,F)$ converges to $f$ w.r.t the supremum norm $\| \cdot \|_\infty$. In the other words, $\mathcal C^\infty (X,F)$ is dense in $\mathcal C^0 (X,F)$.

If this statement does not hold in general. Does it hold in case $X$ is a compact?

Thank you so much for your clarification!

Comment: Banach spaces are never compact, are they? Anyway, you should check this https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone–Weierstrass_theorem .

Comment: Hi @Mindlack, I'm unable to understand what you meant. Could you please be more specific?

Comment: The point is that you do not have a normed space here, unless you restrict yourself to *bounded* continuous functions. And there are no (nontrivial) compact Banach spaces; do you mean a compact subset of a Banach space?

Comment: Thank you so much @TedShifrin! That's exactly what I meant. I've edited my post to reflect your suggestion.

Comment: It's my silly mistake to say compact Banach spaces :((